# Is the omission of commas accetpable in these cases?

Tags: commas

> 1.**The city Melbourne** is the capital of the state of Victoria in the southeast corner of Australia.

Do I have to set off **"Melbourne"** with commas as in **"The city, Melbourne, is the capital of the state of Victoria in the southeast corner of Australia."**?

Or is there no need to add commas?

> 2.The Berlin Games are best remembered for Adolf Hitler’s failed attempt to use them to prove his theories of Aryan racial superiority.
>   As it turned out, the most popular hero of the Games was the
>   **African-American sprinter and long jumper Jesse Owens**.

As for the part **"...was the African-American sprinter and long jumper Jesse Owens"**
Do **"Jesse Owens"** have to be set off by a comma as in **"was the African-American sprinter and long jumper, Jesse Owens"**?

I have asked this question on the other sites as well, but haven't gotten clear answers on it, because their answers are all different. Some of them answered the first one is correct even without adding **"of"** or **"commas"** and the rest answered the first one is wrong without adding **"of"** or **"commas"** while the second is correct.

If the first one is wrong and **"of"** or **"commas"** have to be added, why is the second one correct even without **"commas"**?

Comment: Any commas are entirely optional in your example #1. It ***only*** depends on whether you would expect to ***pause*** at certain points ***in speech***, nothing else. Note that you cannot avoid pausing after ***As it turned out*** in the second example (but it's just a stylistic choice after ***long jumper***).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Then what about in writing? Are 1 and 2 still correct even in writing without commas?

Comment: What about writing? Real language is ***spoken***, and the written form is just a (not always successful) attempt to reflect speech. To repeat myself, the only *sensible* reason for writing a comma is because it reflects a pause in speech (which is entirely optional in your example #1, but there are a couple of places where you "must" pause in #2).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica *"Real language is spoken"* That really hurts my confidence. My writing is much better than my "spoken". Okay, I will go freak out now.

Comment: @AIQ: As a native speaker, obviously I'll normally have a pretty clear idea of where I can/must introduce pauses in speech. But I really have no idea  how useful my advice above is for *learners* (maybe it depends on how pauses work in their *specific* native tongue, I dunno).